# Can anyone explain xml code ie. salesrule_validator_process event in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, xml

```
<events>
    <salesrule_validator_process>
        <observers>
            <new_dicount_coupon>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Test_Mrp_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>newcoupondiscountcal</method>
            </new_dicount_coupon>
        </observers>
    </salesrule_validator_process>
</events>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> salesrule_validator_process event passess the objects as the below code.

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('salesrule_validator_process', array(
     'rule'    => $rule,
     'item'    => $item,
     'address' => $address,
     'quote'   => $quote,
     'qty'     => $qty,
     'result'  => $result,
    ));
```

1. In the mentioned xml, you can access the data in `Test_Mrp_Model_Observer` inside of method `newcoupondiscountcal`
2. `<type>singleton</type>` will return exiting object if already an object is found.

**Some of reference's**

To get Coupon

```
$coupon_code = $quote->getCouponCode();
```

To remove coupon

```
 $quote->setCouponCode('');
 $quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

Comment: yes,  you can suggest what to edit the question in more proper way.

Answer (score 1):

This is for method calling on the event `salesrule_validator_process`.

On this event method `newcoupondiscountcal()` will call from your module observer file. and in this method you can perform your calculation at the time of  salesrule validation.

In this `new_dicount_coupon` is just a name which you have to define.